# Is there a way to view a list of all the classes / functions / globals I have defined in my current dart project when using VS Code?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code, flutter

Visual studio has the object browser where you can view the structure of a project, it lists the namespaces, classes, etc that are defined.  Is there something like this in VS Code for Dart (dart-code)?[image]

Comment: The Outline view gives you this for each file. You can also use the symbols search console (on Windows type `ctrl`+`shift`+`o`, then enter `@:` to group by classes, methods, fields, etc.). But I have no idea if this is possible for the whole project.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a whole project functionality.  I'm guessing this might not be possible as it wouldn't be vs code's responsibility and a plugin and I'm guessing the excellent dart-code doesn't do this.  Thanks for the input (and boo to whoever downvoted this without leaving a comment!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a command in VS Code called "Go to symbol in workspace" bound to `Cmd`+`T` (probably `Ctrl`+`T` for Win/Linux?) that should do what you want. It may include a little more than you want though (it includes referenced packages).

[image: Workspace symbol search]

Comment: Thanks Danny, I was looking for just the current project but this helps :-)